# Bases for free pro-p groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, profinite-groups, free-groups, p-groups

Let $p$ be a prime number, $F$ a free nonabelian finitely generated pro-$p$ group, $L \lhd_o F$ and $Y$ a basis for $L$ with $y \in Y$. Is there a basis $X$ for $F$ such that $y$ is in the abstract subgroup generated by $X$ ?

Comment: Pablo, I don't know how relevant it is to this specific question, but you should look into the theory of profinite and pro-p trees, as developed by Ribes and Zalesskii. (Not in their published book, but in some papers by them and various co-authors, including me.)  This technology makes concrete some of the analogies between profinite (or pro-p) free groups and abstract free groups.

Comment: @HJRW: Thanks for this advice, I will look at this. By the way, can you give me some references (just for me to know where to start from)?

Comment: I wrote a paper with Zalesskii called 'Profinite properties of graph manifolds', which appeared in *Geom. Dedicata*.  You could look at the references in that.

Comment: It seems the answer is no in general. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/181463/variety-of-nilpotent-lie-algebras-or-p-groups: according Barnea's answer, at least for odd $p$ there's a counterexample: namely if $N$ is the intersection of kernels of continuous homomorphisms $F\to\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z}_p)$, then $N\neq\{1\}$ (Zubkov's Theorem) and for every basis $X$ of $F$, if $\Phi$ is the subgroup generated by $X$, we have $\Phi\cap N=\{1\}$. Zubkov's theorem is probably also true for $p=2$.

Comment: @YCor: I don't think I see why there is no basis $X$ such that the abstract subgroup it generates intersects $N$. Furthermore, this question deals not with an arbitrary element but rather with a basis element of an open subgroup.

Comment: @Pablo: Every non-trivial element of a free pro-$p$ group is a basis element of some open subgroup. So you asking whether every element of a  pro-p group (the condition free is not essential) belongs to the abstract subgroup generated by a some smallest generating set.